# Laravel asset file 404

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I upload new file on my server in `public\js\` folder. But I can't access it - 404 error. All other files in folder is fine. I can open it. But if I rename one of this files (for example file named `test.js` and I can access it) to other name (`test.js` to `test2.js`) - I'v got 404 error.

```
https://some/js/app.js - work fine
rename `app.js` to `app2.js`
https://some/js/app2.js - 404 error
```

Is Laravel 5.5 store names of allowed to access files? How can I fix it?

Before renaming

```
ls -l
total 692
drwxr-xr-x 3 chipikby chipikby   4096 Aug 30 22:17 ./
drwxr-xr-x 9 chipikby chipikby   4096 Aug 30 21:50 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 chipikby chipikby  15666 Jun 13 16:11 Sortable.min.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 chipikby chipikby  19983 Aug 30 22:17 app.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 chipikby chipikby 195881 Jun 13 16:11 libraries.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 chipikby chipikby 459664 Aug 30 21:36 new.js
drwxr-xr-x 6 chipikby chipikby   4096 May 22 12:01 tinymce/
```

app.js to app2.js

```
ls -l
drwxr-xr-x 3 chipikby chipikby   4096 Aug 30 22:28 ./
drwxr-xr-x 9 chipikby chipikby   4096 Aug 30 21:50 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 chipikby chipikby  15666 Jun 13 16:11 Sortable.min.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 chipikby chipikby  19983 Aug 30 22:17 app2.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 chipikby chipikby 195881 Jun 13 16:11 libraries.js
-rw-r--r-- 1 chipikby chipikby 459664 Aug 30 21:36 new.js
drwxr-xr-x 6 chipikby chipikby   4096 May 22 12:01 tinymce/
```

**Solved.**

On server all laravel files stored on home derectory with public folder. BUT (i don't know why) they are not in use. I need store asset files at other folder (not laravel project folder). Very strange...

Comment: Can you check owner authorization between app2.js and another file(s) in the public folder. When you changed file name maybe it has been changing owner authorization that file.

Comment: If you are running `php artisan serve`, try closing the command and then run

Comment: @FGDeveloper update quastion. Permissons are similar

Comment: @Ostap34PHP it in on production server. Localy all fine.

Comment: try to clear cache in your browser, or go to anonim. mode

Comment: Your problem may be browser cache? Try cache purge in your browser.

Comment: @Teretto Solved

Comment: how? clear cache work for you?

Comment: @Ostap34PHP i update question

Comment: If you make use of a firewall or anti-DDoS measures like Cloudflare, you have to disable it, clear the cache, and re-enable it to retry.

Answer (score 0):

It may you are uploading your file with wrong permission, check your file owner and permission level, it should be 644.